# What does disk I/O mean in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

My question is pure theoretical regarding the Spark and MapReduce processing.

1. What does disk I/O mean in context of Mapreduce and Spark?
2. I know that in the Spark the data is stored all over memory (RAM) during the computation. Where does MapReduce store the intermediate data? If the answer is disk, what exactly does the disk mean?
3. Does Spark have only 2 disk I/O's during the jobs? How many disk I/O's does MapReduce have?

Answer (score 0):

In Spark, disk I/O refers to the input/output operations performed on disk storage devices during the execution of Spark jobs or tasks. When working with large datasets that cannot fit entirely in memory, Spark may need to read data from disk or write data to disk in order to perform various operations.

Disk I/O typically occurs when Spark needs to read data from external storage, such as reading input data from files stored on a distributed file system like Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS) or writing output data to disk. It can also occur during shuffling of data between different stages or tasks within a Spark application.

Disk I/O operations tend to be slower compared to memory-based operations due to the mechanical nature of disk drives and the need to physically read or write data on disk platters. As a result, minimizing disk I/O is crucial for optimizing Spark application performance.

To mitigate the impact of disk I/O, Spark employs various techniques such as data partitioning, caching, and in-memory processing. By intelligently managing data placement and leveraging memory as much as possible, Spark aims to reduce the need for frequent disk I/O operations, thereby improving overall execution speed. Additionally, utilizing technologies like solid-state drives (SSDs) or distributed storage systems can further enhance disk I/O performance in Spark.